# Visual Studio 2019 getting error C2440 with typedef data type

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm getting that problem and don't know how to solve it:

That error:

```
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'node_t'
```

Code is:

```
node_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * temp3);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp3; i++)
        arr[i] = NULL;
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the assignment `arr[i] = NULL;` is invalid. Replace it with proper initialization of `node_t` (prehaps a structure?) Note that multiple statements should be enclosed in `{}` to use them as loop body.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate which line the error message refers to. It mentions an `'='` operator, but there are three of them in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `arr[i]` is `node_t` which is not a pointer type (I guessed this from the error message).

This code reproduces the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int a, b;
} node_t;


int main() {
  node_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    arr[i] = NULL;    
}
```

You probably need something like this:

```
void initialize_node(node_t *node)
{
  // adapt this to your actual node_t type
  node->a = 0;
  node->b = 0;
}

int main() {
  node_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    initialize_node(&arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL can only be assigned to pointers but by 'arr[i] =  NULL', you are actually dereferencing the pointer and assigning NULL to the struct node_t. That's why you are getting error.

Dereferencing a pointer means getting the value that is stored in the memory
location pointed by the pointer.

arr[i] is same as *(arr+i).